# How can I fix ESLint Parsing Error for unexpected token "/"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, eslint

[image]

```js
const Index = () => (
    <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <Link href="/posts">
            <a>Posts</a>
        </Link>
    </div>
)
```

ESLint is returning a Parsing Error (Unexpected token) for the closing `</p>` tag. What am I missing? Are normal HTML attributes not allowed in JSX? (The `div` seems to work fine)

The exact error is:

```
[eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token "/"
```

- ESLint is installed
- ESLint React is installed
- ESLint React is configured in `.eslintrc.json`

**EDIT:**

- Using VS Code (with ESLint plugin)

Partial `.eslintrc.json`:

```
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true
},
"extends": "eslint:recommended",
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
    "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
    "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": [
    "react"
],
"rules": {
    ...
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely something wrong with the linter. Try removing the line, running the linter and adding the line again.

Comment: @Phiter : Sadly that didn't work

Comment: Please show us your `.eslintrc.json` file. It looks like your eslint parser is not configured to understand JSX.

Comment: @richardgirges : Added

Comment: try retyping the `</p>` there could be some hidden char there.

Comment: @DanielA.White : Sadly, no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what caused the problem, but this solved it for me. I changed the `.eslintrc.json` to the following:

```
{
    //"env": {
    //    "browser": true,
    //    "commonjs": true,
    //    "es6": true
    //},
    "extends": [
        "standard",
        "standard-react"
    ]
}
```

I left in my original `rules` as well.

---

*This problem seems to have multiple different causes, so check out the other answers as well.*

Comment: For me, it was the `"standard-react"` that was the culprit.

Answer (score 17):

I received a similar error in **Visual Studio 2017 (not Code)**.

The error "ESLint encountered a parsing error" occurred at the beginning of an `import` statement.

janniks' solution did not work for me. I suspect because `"es6: true` ["enable[s] all ECMAScript 6 features except for modules"](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments).

Since I'm using TypeScript, I [don't want to use `babel-eslint`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint#what-about-babel-and-babel-eslint), per Sean's answer (though it did resolve the parsing error in a plain JS file).

> The key trade-off can be summarized as: `babel-eslint` supports
>   additional syntax which TypeScript itself does not, but
>   `typescript-eslint` supports creating rules based on type information,
>   which is not available to babel because there is no type-checker.

Instead, I continued to use "@typescript-eslint/parser". Below is my minimal working `.eslintrc`:

```
{
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "quotes": [ "error", "single" ]
    }
}
```

Note: The error was resolved in plain JS files (not TS) even if I removed the `"parser"` line, therefore using the default eslint parser.

Comment: OMG! Thank you!!!

I've spend almost a full day chasing this down. Everyone says use "babel-eslint". Strangely this only worked sporadically. Every time I made a change, it would throw the error again. This seems to have finally fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same issue today while setting up a new React project.  The fix that worked for me was installing the `babel-eslint` package (`npm install babel-eslint --save-dev` or `yarn add babel-eslint -D`).  I then added `"parser": "babel-eslint"` to my `.eslintrc` config file.  This seems to help babel and ESLint get along a little better than using the default parser.

Comment: Hi - this is probably a useful answer - however - it would be much better if you could explain _why_ it solves the problem.